# JS file doesn't work in server

Tags: php, javascript, http, http-request

I've a js file located in my host `http://mywebsite.com/data[0]/data[1]/test.js` that has document.write() function in it.

( data[0] and data[1] are dynamic values that a php module handles them and js output would be different every time these values are chaneged)

when in a html file i use this :

`<script src="http://mywebsite.com/data[0]/data[1]/test.js"></script>`

it doesn't work but when i save an output of the js file (static values are set and no data[0] and data[1] are used ) in localhost and use this :

`<script src="http://localhost/test.js"></script>`

it works!

i think something in http request should be the problem but i don't know what !! : (

any help would be appreciated :(

Comment: Does the resulting HTML contain `data[0]` or has it been replaceed by PHP? If it has been replaced, what is the resulting HTML?

Comment: @pimvdb, data[0] and data[1] are variables that module checks them and  according to them js contents will differ.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your scenario. Is the file `data[0]/data[1]/test.js` literally requested? If not, what file is requested?

Comment: @pimvdb, please see my comment in George answer.

Comment: `http://systemforoosh.com/ads/js/0/1` loads when navigating to it, but not as a `<script src=...>` tag (Bad Request). Perhaps it depends on the `Referer` header sent, but I'm not sure if you can change that.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what `data[0]` or `data[1]` output I would guess it is these and you are incorrectly linking to the file.

If you are unable to post your website as an example I suggest you view the source (normally right click on the page and click view source) of your file and click the link (should be possible in most modern browsers) to your javascript file, if you don't see your javascript file you are linking to it incorrectly.

If you could link to the page I could help you further.

Comment: when i click the link the contents are there but as clear as above that i said, it doesn't work in that condition. linking's correct.

Comment: @Revo If linkage is correct then we would need to see the javascript code as it must be a js error. A link to your website would be good as I don't find your question clear.

Comment: use this : use this : `<script type="text/javascript"> var systemforoosh_affiliate_id = 66;var adsBgColor = '#FFFFFF';var adsBorderColor = '#FFFFFF';var adsSize = '100%';</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://systemforoosh.com/ads/js/0/1"></script>`

Comment: Your code makes no sense at `http://systemforoosh.com/ads/js/0/1` see: `var systemforoosh_rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000);
var systemforoosh_url = window.location.href.replace('http://','').replace('-','@#$@').replace(/\//g,'-');
var systemforoosh_src = 'http://systemforoosh.com/ads/show/0/1/'+systemforoosh_url+'/'+systemforoosh_rand;
var new_script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="' + systemforoosh_src + '"></script>';
document.write(new_script);`you are adding a random number to the url between 1-999,999 so you are trying to load non existent js files.

Comment: as also pimvdb said :  http://systemforoosh.com/ads/js/0/1 loads when navigating to it, but not as a <script src=...> tag (Bad Request). Perhaps it depends on the Referer header sent, but I'm not sure if you can change that.

Comment: @Revo Try explicitly naming the file so instead of `http://systemforoosh.com/ads/js/0/1`search for `http://systemforoosh.com/ads/js/0/1.js` and putting that into the `<script src="" />`